# Angular Ionic - Make modal draggable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is there a way to make the modal draggable in ionic 6?

Below is my code.

```
 openModal() {
        return this.modalController.create({
          component: MyModal,
          cssClass: 'large-modal'
        });
      }
```

CSS:

```
.large-modal .modal-wrapper {
    --height: 500px;
    --width: 500px;
}
```